# Why does blackberry and Android SDK need old versions of Eclipse IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry, sdk, compatibility

I thought it was only for blackberry that you had to do this, but watching a youtube video about getting started with Android, it says that you need Eclipse Galileo (3.5.x) too.

My question is if there is some sort of technical reason why this SDK simpy can't keep  compatible with the newer versions of Eclipse.  Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Why did you look to youtube for this info?  Why wouldn't you go to the source for the tools (android/blackberry/eclipse)?

Comment: in blackberry developers it says that it has to be Eclipse Galileo in order to have the plugin working correctly; I've used it before.

But with android, this video totally surprised me with the same 'compatibility issues' blackberry java development seems to have.  Hence, the question.

Comment: I use the latest eclipse version. And just work fine.

Comment: you use the latest eclipse version, with BB or with android?

Answer (score 3):

Generally why things like this happen are: The developer has integrated on more than just a surface level with a particular version of the IDE, and to make the integration compatible with a newer version of the IDE would require more effort than they're willing to put in (or, they're doing it, but it's not done yet). Since Eclipse versions essentially feature freeze and just move on to the next version, the developers can rely on no significant platform changes being backported at a later date (breaking their integration), and so they feel comfortable saying you can get a particular version of the Eclipse IDE and the integration will work.

Incidentally, you can get these [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding Android:* There is no reason. The Android SDK runs fine with a new Eclipse Indigo.
That video was probably just old.

Can't speak for blackberry though.

Comment: I develop android apps on eclipse Indigo. It crashes sometimes on overload. But even galileo used to crash.

Comment: As said, no problem here. Developing android since galileo/Android 2.1 on a linux and a windows machine with both the most recent versions for sdk and eclipse at any given time. All smooth, no crashes at all. Maybe an issue with your machine.

Comment: Could it be issue with java version?. I have java 7 now. It crashed on java 6 update 18 too. Dont know about previous versions.

Comment: To be honest it's hard to diagnose here (and it's not the right place). Runs fine for me with 6 update 18 definitely, have to check if i have 7 on my win7 machine yet. Even no isses with the OpenJDK. But it could be anything, starting from an old other plugin in eclipse (e.g. for git/memory analysis/..), to a bad written driver, up to slightly defect memory or a overheated machine due to not optimal ventilation. Try installing a second eclipse instance (just unzip it somewhere) and only install the adt plugin. See if that runs stable.

Comment: I think increasing -XXpermSize should fix it. I'll try that. Thanks for making me aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I started doing Blackberry development with Eclipse Galileo, then later upgraded to Helios and it still works (it does occasionally crash/freeze). I have not tried Indigo yet.